# Strange behavior of a QString in a QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

In the code below, Base_Dialog has a variable called name of type QString*.

```
#ifndef BASE_DIALOG_HPP
#define BASE_DIALOG_HPP
#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>

class Main_Dialog;
class Base_Dialog:public QDialog
{
protected:
    Main_Dialog* main_dlg_;
    QDialog* caller_;
    QString* name;//<--- Here is this variable
 public:
    Base_Dialog(QString n,Main_Dialog* main_dlg, QDialog* caller, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QDialog* set_caller(QDialog *);
    QDialog* clear_caller();
    Main_Dialog* clear_main_dlg();

};

#endif // BASE_DIALOG_HPP
//cpp for Base_Dialog
Base_Dialog::Base_Dialog(QString n,Main_Dialog* main_dlg, QDialog*caller, QWidget *parent):
    QDialog(parent),
    main_dlg_(main_dlg),
    caller_(caller),
    name(new QString(n))//<---Here is this variable initialized
{/*eb*/}

QDialog* Base_Dialog::set_caller(QDialog *new_caller)
{
 QDialog* old_caller = caller_;
 QDialog* tmp = new QDialog(new_caller);
 caller_ = tmp;
 Base_Dialog* a = static_cast<Base_Dialog*>(caller_);

 QString stmp  = *(a->name);//<---Here I'm trying to read this variable but I'm getting error:"Inferior stopped...." and on panel I'm getting: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Base_Dialog' value 
 return old_caller;
}
#ifndef _1DIALOG_HPP
#define _1DIALOG_HPP
#include "Base_Dialog.hpp"
#include "ui__1Dialog.h"

class Main_Dialog;
class _1Dialog : public Base_Dialog, private Ui::_1Dialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit _1Dialog(Main_Dialog* main_dlg, QDialog*caller, QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void _2clicked();
    void caller_clicked();
    void main_clicked();
};

#endif // _1DIALOG_HPP
//cpp for _1Dialog
_1Dialog::_1Dialog(Main_Dialog* main_dlg, QDialog*caller, QWidget *parent) :
    Base_Dialog("1",main_dlg,caller,parent)//Here I'm passing "1" as a value for 'name' variable
{
    setupUi(this);
}
```

Basically the problem I have is that after successfully setting a value to a variable called name I cannot read it back. I'm trying to read this variable but I'm getting error:"Inferior stopped...." and on panel I'm getting: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Base_Dialog' value. Please see comments in the code. That way it will be easier for you to follow.

Comment: If you need to communicate across dialogs, use signals and slots, rather than passing pointers to each dialog.

Comment: Why are you making your `QString` a pointer? All that accomplishes is making things more complex.

Comment: Don't use pointers for QString - that's unnecessary.

Comment: Also, use `object_cast` instead of static cast. It is kind of like `dynamic_cast` but is especially made for things in the `QObject` hierarchy. If it returns `NULL`, then the cast is invalid (which I suspect is the case).

Comment: @EvanTeran and what are the advantages of object_cast over dynamic_cast?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I've change it back to "non pointer" but I'm still getting this same behavior. Even though during initialization I can clearly see that this variable was properly initialized. I suspect a bug in Qt.

Comment: @user336635: `qobject_cast` is faster than dynamic cast since it has a specialized use case (`QObject`s only), doesn't require RTTI (since it leverages the Qt MOC system) and unlike `dynamic_cast` it is guaranteed to work across dynamic library boundaries. Do yourself a favor, and change your `static_cast` to a `qobject_cast`.

Comment: Also note, that I had a typo in my second comment above. It is **`qobject_cast`**, not `object_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is unrelated to your variable. You are running a previous build and you can't link your current code, because you are missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro from your `Base_Dialog` class declaration. Also, it probably doesn't make much sense to allocate the `name` variable on the heap.

Another huge problem with your code is this line:

```
Base_Dialog* a = static_cast<Base_Dialog*>(caller_);
```

`Base_Dialog` inherits from (extends) `QDialog*`. It means that all `Base_Dialog`s are `QDialog`s, but that **does not** mean that all `QDialog`s are `Base_Dialog`s. Your are instructing the compiler to treat a `QDialog*` pointer as if it was a `Base_Dialog*`, regardless if that originally points to a `Base_Dialog` or something else. When you try to dereference a member that doesn't actually exist in the pointed object, you will try to access uninitilized memory.

I suggest to read up on OOP and lessen your usage of pointers because without understanding these things you will get such errors everywhere.

Comment: #Tamas Szelei thanks, I've added this Q_OBJECT macro, but now I'm getting undefined reference to vtable for Base_Dialog, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. Sometimes you need to delete the generated Makefiles manually from your build directory, too.

Comment: #Tamas Szelei, indeed, after removing makefiles, this problem with undefined references disappeared. Unfortunately I'm still getting the error when try to read 'name' variable.

Comment: Most of the time this error happens because you have an uninitialized pointer, so you might be trying to read it before it is initialized. Unless you really, explicitly need to use a pointer, don't do it. Just declare it as `QString name`. Also, I just realized another big mistake in your code, see my edit.

Comment: #Tamas Szelei I don't understand why you saying that this is a mistake. All of my dialogs inherit from Base_Dialog so it seems reasonable to cast them to Base_Dialog, wouldn't that seem right?

Comment: #Tamas Szelei, I'm quite familiar with OOP and I believe that if object Y inherits from a class X then it is ok and in good OOP practise to cast this object if necessary to X* don't you think so?

Comment: #Tamas Szelei I also after giving it some though strongly disagree with you when you say that Q_OBJECT macro should be added to Base_Dialog. AFAIC this macro is needed only if you using signals/slots in your class. Without them this macro is unnecessary.